# Why do I have to keep a reference to my UIViewController to prevent it from being Garbage Collected?

Tags: xamarin.ios

The question's title may sound stupid, but I have beenw wondering about the following issue:

- Add a `UIView` to the app's window. It will not rotate, because there is no controller which implements `ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation`(): `window.AddSubView(myView)`;
- Now take a UIViewController that creates its view in `LoadView()` override `ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation()`. Then do this: `window.AddSubView(myController.View);`

In the latter case the view rotates as expected. Why? Because its view controller tells it to do so. **But how does the view know which controller it belongs to? I did not tell it!** From the ObjC people I learned that each view has a "_`viewDelegate`" property which refers back to the view's controller.
But if that is true, why do I then have to keep a reference of myController, best in a member variable, to prevent it from being Garbage Collected? My test case in AppDelegate.cs:

```
public static AddView()
{
  var myController = new MyController();
  window.AddSubView(myController.View);
}
```

The view will be correct first time, then the controller seems to be gone. However, the code below works as expected:

```
var myController = null;
public static AddView()
{
  this.myController = new MyController();
  window.AddSubView(myController.View);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monotouch is built on top of iOS framework which at its core is using reference counting as its memory management. Even after adding garbage collection it does not affect the underlying framework. In the case of UIView it is true that it holds a reference to its UIViewController and the reason why your controller gets garbage collected is because all delegates in iOS are assigned and NOT retained. Apples memory management guide explains this in greater detail under "Weak References to Objects": http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I know the document you linked but I seem to have missed that delegates are assigned and not retained. That explains it of course!
Now the only open thing remaining is: why is this "_viewDelegate" property such a secrect and makes everybody pass "this" (being the UIViewController) to the view if the view would already know about its controller! But: different topic.

Comment: Generally you should not need that information. The design pattern is for data to flow into the view from your controller, not out. UIView should only be responsible for displaying your data. UIViewController is responsible for managing data and responding to user actions. If you need to listen to UIControl events then you should be setting those up during viewdidload and removing them in viewdidunload and dealloc.

Comment: Yeah, but if my controller manages a UITableView and I implement the view's GetCell() it is just practical to ask the controller for data at position x, hence I need the controller reference.

Comment: I see what you mean. While I am unfamiliar with how monotouch wraps the objc classes I do know that UITableView has two separate delegates. This allows you to break up the responsibility for managing that view in many ways. In your case I assume you have a simple use for it so it seems overly complex and retarded the way tables were implemented. The 6th paragraph talking about delegates under overview at this link may provide helpful insight into each delegates use: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html